# How to apply a formula to each cell of a numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, arcpy

I am trying to take an existing numpy array and apply a formula to each cell of the array.  I have the code below but it returns the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gTemp\Text-1.py", line 5, in 
    myarray = 0.1236 * math.tan(myarray / 2842.5 + 1.1863)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I am new to numpy and I am looking for skill level appropriate advice.  Here is my existing code.

```
import arcpy
import numpy
import math
myarray =  numpy.load(r"E:\depthtester2.npy")
myarray = 0.1236 * math.tan(myarray / 2842.5 + 1.1863)
myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myarray,arcpy.Point(0.0,0.0),1.0, 1.0, -99999.0 )
myRaster.save("E:\deptht")
print "done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `math.tan()`, use [`numpy.tan()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tan.html).  The numpy functions are designed to work elementwise on numpy arrays.

Comment: That worked!  I appreciate your advice and effort ,Warren.